# How can I speed up this script?

Tags: python, forms, urllib2, form-submit

I am required to retrieve 8000 answers from a website for research purposes (auto filling a form and submitting it 8000 times). I wrote the below script but when I run it after 20 submits python stops working and I'm unable to get what I need. Could you please help me find the problem with my script?

```
from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen, urljoin
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import mechanize
import time

URL = "url of the website"
br = mechanize.Browser() # Creates a browser
br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

def fetch(val):
    br.open(URL) # Open the login page
    br.select_form(nr=0) # Find the login form
    br['subject']='question'
    br['value'] =val
    br.set_all_readonly(False)
    resp = br.submit()
    data = resp.read()
    br.reload()
    x=data.find("the answer is:")
    if x!=-1:
        ur=data[x:x+100]
        print ur

val_list =val_list # This list is available and contains 8000 different values

for i in range(0,8000):
    fetch(val_list[i])
```

Comment: please indent your code. I would do it for you but can't understand where the indents start and end.

Comment: Aren't you hitting some kind of limit on the website? Maybe you are getting banned/filtered

Comment: This is your website, right? Or you have written permission from the owner of the website? Otherwise `br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots` is, at best, rude, and at worst very illegal.

Comment: Can you describe the syptoms more precisely. What do you mean, "python stops working"?

Comment: Thank you all, actually I found that this website doesn't allow one ip to send more than 20 requests at a time and python doesn't stop working but just doesn't print any answers!

Comment: Btw: instead of the for loop over range, you can just do `for val in val_list: fetch(val)` or one-liner `[fetch(val) for val in val_list]`

Answer (score 0):

Having used `mechanize` in the past to do a similar data-scraping kind of thing, you're almost certainly getting limited by the website as [Erbureth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624664/erbureth) mentioned. Usually websites have a way to monitor connections to filter out exactly the type of thing you're attempting, and for good reason.

Putting aside for a moment whatever the purpose of your script may be and moving to your question of why is doesn't work: At the very least, I would put some delays in there so you're not trying to access the site repeatedly in such a short time span. Put a few seconds of pause between calls, and maybe it will work. (Although then you'll have to let it run for hours.)

Comment: Thank you, actually I found that this website doesn't allow one ip to send more than 20 requests at a time so python doesn't stop working just doesn't print any answers!